# Why can't I use $size and a $project step, and then filter the result with $match?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have this type of object in a Mongo collection:

```
[  ...
   {array: ['keyword1', 'keyword2'], someField: "text", ...}
   ...
]
```

I want to use an aggregation like this:

```
db.getCollection("SomeCollection").aggregate(
    [   ...
        { "$project" : { "size" : {"$size" : "$someField"}}}
        { "$match": {size: {$gte: 2} } }
        ...
])
```

When I add the match step, I have this error message:

```
{  
    "ok" : 0.0, 
    "errmsg" : "The argument to $size must be an array, but was of type: missing",
    "code" : NumberInt(17124), 
    "codeName" : "Location17124"
}
```

I'm sure that there are arrays with more than 2 elements.

I'm curious why this error. For the record, I have a workaround using $where in a "coll.find" query.

Answer (score 0):

The aggregation is returning an error because the first stage is passing a non-array field (`someField`) to the `$size` operator. The value passed to $size [must resolve to an array](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/#behavior):

> The argument for $size must resolve to an array. If the argument for
>   $size is missing or does not resolve to an array, $size errors.

It is also worth noting that the error is saying `but was of type: missing` because the field in your document has a different name (`somefield`) that the aggregation (`someField`), meaning that the aggregation is passing nothing value to the `$size` operator.

Comment: Thaks for the answer. I mistyping the fields name in the question, I just edited. I'm sure that "array" is always that, and the project stage have no error if I used without the match stage.

Comment: The issue is that the $project stage is trying to compute the size of `someField`, which is not an array. Were you intending of computing the size of the `array` field instead?